# jquery.validate .valid() only flagging first two rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Most major browsers except IE9:

http://jsfiddle.net/tdoherty/nxB39/

If I step trough the code from the .valid() call, all four required fields are flagged, but if I let it run in real time it only ever displays the first two.

Reproduced in Firefox 11.0, Chrome 18.0.1025.162 m, Safari 5.1.5, Opera 11.62

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the .focus() call in the highlight() call which in turn triggers the onfocusin callback to unhighlight() the element.